# Php code to get contents of two different files save them in two different arrays and match the content of one array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried this code but it is not working as expected:

```
 $text = file("2001.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
 $words = file("g.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
 for($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++)
 {
    for($j=0;$j<count($text);$j++)
    {
       if ($text[$j]==$words[$i])
       { 
          echo "hello";
       }

    }
  }
```

the arrays are not matching is there any other solution??

Comment: no now while pasting it i hv marked it in comments because i was trying some other codes.

Comment: even though i remove commenting the code is'nt working

Comment: How are you trying to match the files?  The way you have it, the lines would have to be exactly the same.

Comment: this is my output when i print $text and $words

Comment: Array ( [0] => a [1] => m [2] => n [3] => b [4] => k [5] => c [6] => v [7] => f [8] => g [9] => l [10] => h ) for $text

Comment: Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f [6] => g [7] => h ) for $words

Comment: if ($text[$j]==$words[$i])
                  { 
                     $count++;
                     echo "hello";
                  }
this condition is not working

Comment: What does `print_r(array_intersect($words, $text));` return?

Comment: print_r(array_intersect($words, $text)); returns Array ( )

Comment: Then there must be a different underlying problem as the array_intersect returns all the intersecting (duplicate) values between two arrays.

Comment: oh !! okie i will check it out. But other than this there is no other way to match the content of one file to other file and count the matched key words?

Comment: Comment out the loops and run `echo "<pre>"; print_r($words); print_r($text);` then update your question with the outputs.

Comment: You could review this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108004/how-would-i-compare-two-text-files-for-matches-with-php

Comment: the comparison of arrays is not working

Answer (score 0):

FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES should be used with both file() calls if you are looking to compare lines in the file like you are.

FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES will skip adding a newline to each array element.  If you are doing this on one and not the other, then you're likely to have an array of:

`array('a', 'b', 'c');`

and

`array('a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n');`

It would be helpful for you to update your question with the contents of the two arrays because we don't know what is in your text files.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($words);
print_r($text);
```